# Не получается получить элемент по тегу.(Используя расширение)

Tags: javascript, dom

У меня есть расширение для браузера

манифест

```
  { "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "EI Analyzer Plugin",
    "description": "ESC",
    "version": "1.0",

    "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["http://*.youtube.com/*"],
     "run_at": "document_idle",
     "js": ["tester.js"]
   }
 ],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

простейшая HTML страница с кнопкой

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Analyzer</title>
        <script src = "popup.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>ANALIZE WRS</h1>
        <button id="checkPage">Check this page now!</button>
        <p id = "mes" > test </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

При нажатии кнопки я хочу изучить содержимое страницы открытой в текущей вкладке. ( В качестве примера взял ютуб).

Код скрипта :

```
window.onload = function(){
var button_js = document.getElementById('checkPage');
button_js.addEventListener("click",f1);
}


function f1(){
    alert(document.getElementsByClassName('style-scope ytd-app').length);       
}

 Получается 0. Если такую же команду отправить в консоль находясь на ютубе, 
 ответ будет 30.
```

Пожалуйста подскажите что я делаю не так ? Как конкретно обратиться 
   к элементу на текущей странице(а не странице расширения).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в манифесте
в этой строке

```
"matches": ["http://*.youtube.com/*"],
```

Пропущена буква **s**

Помимо этого, код который встраивается под сайт я вынес в отдельный файл, и всё стало работать.

Оставлю, вдруг кому пригодится.